# Nginx Configuration for Redirecting URL

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I want to redirect something like this /atpf/xyz -> /atp/xyz, I have a configuration like this, but doesn't seem to work

```
location /atpfe {
    rewrite ^/atp/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://backend-atp;
}
```

Can someone suggest?

Comment: The location `/atpfe` doesn't match either of the URIs in your question and the `rewrite` statement changes `/atp/xyz` to `/xyz`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to this and worked:

```
  location /atpfe {
            rewrite ^/atpfe/(.*)$ /atp/$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://backend-atppub;
        }
```

Wasn't fully aware of the rewrite functionality